# Firebase Android stops synching

Tags: android, firebase

Intermittently my Android Firebase app stops syncing; data written by Android is not reflected in the cloud.

If I simply toggle flight mode on and off it immediately starts working again.

All tests were done using modern AT&T Galaxy phones on their mobile network.  No WiFi testing was done. All Gradle dependencies are up to date.

Has anyone seen this discussed?

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: Realtime Database or Firestore?

Comment: Realtime Database.  I don't have a minimum project to share as an example. Nor do I have reproduction steps. The code is like any of the "firebase chat" examples.  Occasionally adding a chat message using the device is not committed to Firebase cloud.  Toggle flight mode and it picks up again.